# What is a recommended approach to communicate with Activity from Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am sure about the approach of using Interface to communicate with Activity. But can I call a public method of the activity directly from Fragment using getActivity() or should I stick with Interface. If you are suggesting to use Interface can I know the deadfalls of using my other methods. ?

Answer (score 0):

Either you create an interface callback (https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)  or you use EventBus library (http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/)

Answer (score 0):

Its your choice.You can call the method like this also.

**From fragment to activty:**

```
((YourActivityClassName)getActivity()).yourPublicMethod();
```

Comment: Yeah I am using this. But I would like to know the downfalls of using it. I know with Listener I could communicate with my fragment from Anywhere. Also I would be using only one activity.